# apply vector of functions to vector of arguments

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to take in a list of functions, `funclist`, and return a new function which takes in a list of arguments, `arglist`, and applies the `i`th function in `funclist` to the `i`th element of `arglist`, returning the results in a list:

```
def myfunc(funclist):
    return lambda arglist: [ funclist[i](elt) for i, elt in enumerate(arglist) ]
```

This is not optimized for parallel/vectorized application of the independent functions in `funclist` to the independent arguments in `argvec`. Is there a built-in function in python or numpy (or otherwise) that will return a more optimized version of the `lambda`  above? It would be similar in spirit to `map` or `numpy.vectorize` (but obviously not the same), and so far I haven't found anything.

Comment: `[f(args) for f, args in zip(funclist, arglist)]`

Comment: Will `zip` be faster than `enumerate`? Yes because it avoids the `.__getitem__` into funclist?

Comment: it absolutely will. use `itertools.izip` to make it even more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

In `numpy` terms true vectorization means performing the iterative stuff in compiled code.  Usually that requires using `numpy` functions that work with whole arrays, doing thing like addition and indexing.

`np.vectorize` is a way of iterate of several arrays, and using their elements in a function that does not handle arrays.  It doesn't do much in compiled code, so does not improve the speed much.  It's most valuable as a way of applying `numpy` broadcasting rules to your own scalar function.

`map` is a variant on list comprehension, and has basically the same speed.  And a list comprehension has more expressive power, working with several lists.

`@Tore's` zipped comprehension is a clear expression this task

```
[f(args) for f, args in zip(funclist, arglist)]
```

`map` can work with several input lists:

```
In [415]: arglist=[np.arange(3),np.arange(1,4)]
In [416]: fnlist=[np.sum, np.prod]
In [417]: [f(a) for f,a in zip(fnlist, arglist)]
Out[417]: [3, 6]
In [418]: list(map(lambda f,a: f(a), fnlist, arglist))
Out[418]: [3, 6]
```

Your version is a little wordier, but functionally the same.

```
In [423]: def myfunc(funclist):
     ...:     return lambda arglist: [ funclist[i](elt) for i, elt in enumerate(arglist) ]

In [424]: myfunc(fnlist)
Out[424]: <function __main__.myfunc.<locals>.<lambda>>
In [425]: myfunc(fnlist)(arglist)
Out[425]: [3, 6]
```

It has the advantage of generating a function that can be applied to different arglists:

```
In [426]: flist=myfunc(fnlist)
In [427]: flist(arglist)
Out[427]: [3, 6]
In [428]: flist(arglist[::-1])
Out[428]: [6, 0]
```

I would have written `myfunc` more like:

```
def altfun(funclist):
   def foo(arglist):
       return [f(a) for f,a in zip(funclist, arglist)]
   return foo
```

but the differences are just stylistic.

================

Time test for `zip` v `enumerate`:

```
In [154]: funclist=[sum]*N
In [155]: arglist=[list(range(N))]*N
In [156]: sum([funclist[i](args) for i,args in enumerate(arglist)])
Out[156]: 499500000
In [157]: sum([f(args) for f,args in zip(funclist, arglist)])
Out[157]: 499500000

In [158]: timeit [funclist[i](args) for i,args in enumerate(arglist)]
10 loops, best of 3: 43.5 ms per loop

In [159]: timeit [f(args) for f,args in zip(funclist, arglist)]
10 loops, best of 3: 43.1 ms per loop
```

Basically the same.  But `map` is 2x faster

```
In [161]: timeit list(map(lambda f,a: f(a), funclist, arglist))
10 loops, best of 3: 23.1 ms per loop
```

Packaging the iteration in a callable is also faster

```
In [165]: timeit altfun(funclist)(arglist)
10 loops, best of 3: 23 ms per loop
In [179]: timeit myfunc(funclist)(arglist)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
```